# Update all mysql records from one table into another

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1 contains all the fields from table2. I need to update table1 with the all the records from table2.
I found this:

```
UPDATE 
    table1 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON (table2.id = table1.id)
SET 
    table1.field1 = table2.field1,
    table1.field2 = table2.field2;
```

But I have too many fields and this would take forever to write. How can I update all the fields from table2 into table1? I can´t seem to find the answer, please help.

Comment: delete all records and insert them again? `insert into table1 select * from table2`

Comment: Do `table1` and `table2` have exactly the same column structure? _Exactly_ the same with the same column order?

Comment: If so, and you have `unique` indices you could [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: Type it once and save what you typed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with MySQL, but if you can get a list of column names, perhaps with:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable FROM mydb
```

Then you can paste those into Excel and build your query, just paste your field names in column `A` , throw this in `B1`:

```
="table1."&A1&" = table2."&A1&","
```

And copy down.